# Node.js Microsoft SQL Server Insert JSON object in a table using mssql

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server, express

I am trying to insert JSON object data into a table in Microsoft SQL Server using `mssql`.

I get 2 errors:

Error 1: `insertBuildingQuery` throws the following error upon execution:

> RequestError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

**Question 1:** what is the correct way of inserting a JSON object without having to write multiple lines or question marks manually?

Error 2: if I manually build the values in the query string and something like:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (<column_names>) 
VALUES (<column_values>)
```

I get the following error because of acceptable null values in `water_usage_id` & `gas_usage_id` both of which are INT columns in SQL Server.

> RequestError: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'null' to data type int.

The reason that I identified for this is because the null values are not getting converted to actual null and are being passed as string values to an int column.

**Question 2:** How to insert null values in the Microsoft SQL Server from Node.js?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

My JS file (please ignore the Schema validation parts):

```
const { poolPromise } = require('../models/cloudSqlServerDb');
const buildingSchema = require('../models/buildingSchemaValidation');
var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;

const addNewBuilding = async (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    if(body != null && Object.keys(body).length !== 0){
      try{
          const pool = await poolPromise;
          
          var buildingData = {
              "site_id": body.form.site_id ,
              "logger_id": body.form.logger_id ,
              "number_of_floors": body.form.number_of_floors ,
              "population": body.form.population != undefined ? body.form.population : null ,
              "water_usage_id": body.form.water_usage_id != undefined ? body.form.water_usage_id : null ,
              "gas_usage_id": body.form.gas_usage_id != undefined ? body.form.gas_usage_id : null ,
              "manager_name": body.form.manager_name != undefined ? body.form.manager_name : null ,
              "manager_phone": body.form.manager_phone != undefined ? body.form.manager_phone : null ,
              "manager_email": body.form.manager_email != undefined ? body.form.manager_email : null
            }
        
        // Validate if received all required fields or not before hitting the DB
        var v = new Validator();
        var buildingValidationResult = v.validate(buildingData, buildingSchema, {required: true});

        if(buildingValidationResult.valid){
          // My Error 2:
          /*
          let buildingValues = "('" + buildingData.site_id + "', '" + buildingData.logger_id + "', '" + buildingData.number_of_floors + "', '" + buildingData.population + "', '" + buildingData.water_usage_id + "', '" + buildingData.gas_usage_id + "', '" + buildingData.manager_name + "', '" + buildingData.manager_phone + "', '" + buildingData.manager_email + "')";
          const insertBuildingQuery = pool
            .request()
            .query('INSERT INTO building (site_id, logger_id, number_of_floors, population, water_usage_id, gas_usage_id, manager_name, manager_phone, manager_email) VALUES ' + buildingValues);
            */

          // My Error 1:
          const insertBuildingQuery = pool
            .request()
            .query('INSERT INTO building SET ?', buildingData);

          await insertBuildingQuery
            .then((result) => {
              if(result.rowsAffected[0] == 1){
                console.log("Building inserted: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                res.status(201).send("Building data inserted Successfully!").end();
              }
            });
        }
        else{
          console.log("Schema Validation Failed for: " + JSON.stringify(buildingData));
          res.status(400).send("Some or all parts of Building details are missing in request").end();
        }
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log("Error at adding New Building: ");
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err).end();
      }
    }
    else{
        console.log("Building details not found in request");
        res.status(400).send("Some or all parts of Building details are missing in request").end();
    }
}

module.exports = {
  addNewBuilding
}
```

Create Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE building (
    building_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    site_id INT NOT NULL, -- FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES site(site_id),
    logger_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    number_of_floors INT NOT NULL,
    population INT,
    water_usage_id INT NULL,
    gas_usage_id INT NULL,
    manager_name VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    manager_phone VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    manager_email VARCHAR(50) NULL
);
```

It is a cloud hosted SQL Server.

How I am creating the pool in `cloudSqlServerDb.js`:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');

const createPool = async () => {
    const config = {pool: {}, options: {}};
    config.user = "<user name>";
    config.password = "<password>";
    config.database = "<db name>";
    config.server = '<server address>';
    config.port = <port number>;
    // ...
    config.connectionTimeout = 30000;
    config.pool.acquireTimeoutMillis = 30000;
    config.pool.idleTimeoutMillis = 600000
    config.pool.max = 5;
    config.pool.min = 1;
    config.pool.createRetryIntervalMillis = 200;
  
    config.options.trustServerCertificate = true;
    return await mssql.connect(config);
};

let pool;
const poolPromise = createPool()
  .then(async pool => {
    // await ensureSchema(pool);
    console.log('Connected to SQL Server!')
    return pool;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
});

module.exports = {
    // establishConnection,
    poolPromise,
    mssql
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SET` syntax? This seems like MySQL, not Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I think I got that wrong. I don't know the alternate syntax of inserting JSON object to MS SQL Server.